# Set the port number in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am going to develop a windows service. When the service starts, there is a port with it. My question is that can we assign a specific port number to it? Example, port number is "55431".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you're using WCF as the communication layer, you would just configure the binding/protocol to listen to as part of the service configuration. In your service's `OnStart()` method you would register the port. You would un-register it, when the service stops.

[Complete Walk-Through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx)

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
// Configure a binding on a TCP port
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

string address = "net.tcp://localhost:55431/myservice"

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, address);
host.Open();
}
```

Comment: I was not talking WCF, I meant windows service.

Comment: Yes, i know. You would use WCF components in your Windows Service to create a binding to a certain port & protocol.

Comment: If so, can you provide code snippet? I have not found such similar materials online.

Comment: It look great, so we can also put the address in app.config?(Yours is localhost).

Comment: Here is a great walk-through of the complete process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

Comment: Nice. But how does this work in the 'Worker Service template' in .NET Core 3.0? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the "Worker Service template" in .NET Core 3.1, this might be helpful as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Search for `UseUrls`. There you will find the solution, something like:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The main method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">Some arguments.</param>
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://*:8084")
        .Build();

    host.RunAsService();
}
```

should run the service as worker template with a specified port.

Answer (score 0):

You can either open a socket to listen on a specific port, or configure WCF to use the given port. Ports are only required for out of process network communication.

Comment: How to open a socket to listen on a specific port? I don't have the experience.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to use sockets in your service?

If yes

```
        IPAddress[] localIpAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(_ => _.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();

        //Listener
        Socket ListenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ListenerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localIpAddresses[0], Port)); //Port goes here
        ListenerSocket.Listen(100);
```