# How To Set a Port For a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, port

I've created a new Windows service and want to setup API calls to it. Is it possible to assign a specific port number to the Windows service? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the port number in windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389620/set-the-port-number-in-windows-service)

Comment: What do you mean by "setup API calls" ? Please edit your question to add more details. A "Windows service" does NOT listen on a port. Is your query about WCF Service or ASP.Net Web API2 ? In these cases, there is a port and any of these can be configured to use a port if hosted in the service.

Comment: If you're using the "Worker Service template" in .NET Core 3.1 (In case someone finds this question while searching), I have posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59820362/5536006